# jQuery.get vs window.open difference

Tags: jquery, window.open

I am trying to download file in my JSP servlet application.
As far as i know jQuery.get() and window.open() both send get requests.
I can easily download file with window.open(CSVURL) however if i try the same thing with jQuery.get(),it does not download. "doGet() function" in servlet runs but nothing is downloaded and there are no errors at console logs.

This code downloads file

```
  $("#exportcsv").click(function() {
            window.open(SomeURL);
        });
```

This does not

```
 $("#exportcsv").click(function() {
            jQuery.get(CSVURL,Data).done(function() {});
        });
```

This is my Java download code on servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        downloadFile(somepath, req, resp);
    }


protected void downloadFile(String path, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        File file = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        ServletOutputStream outstream = null;
        try {
            String fileName = "csv";
            resp.reset();
            file = new File(path);
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            resp.setContentType("text/csv");
            resp.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            outstream = resp.getOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copyLarge(in, outstream);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn(e.getMessage());
        } finally {

            IOUtils.closeQuietly(outstream);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
            if (file != null)
                file.delete();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as i know jQuery.get() and window.open() both send get requests.

Yes, but with two significant differences:

1. `jQuery.get` uses ajax, which is subuject to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). `window.open` does not, and is not. So if the request is for a URL in another origin (different host, different port, and/or different protocol), `jQuery.get` will fail at the browser end (by default; [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) can be used on the server to allow it), but `window.open` will not.
2. I don't think `jQuery.get` triggers the browser's default handling for the `Content-Disposition: attachment; ...` header.

---

> Problem might be caused by header. Could you suggest any workaround to download file without opening new tab?

The way I've generally triggered file downloads is to post a form (since I've usually needed POST for this) to a hidden iframe. On Chrome and Firefox it doesn't open any windows; on IE, it does, but only briefly before the Save As dialog appears.

For a GET request, I believe you can dynamically add an `a` element with the `href` and the [`download` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download) and artificially click it:

```
var a = $("<a download></a>")
        .attr("href", theURL)
        .css("display", "none")
        .appendTo(document.body)
        .click();
setTimeout(function() {
    a.remove();
    a = undefined;
}, 500);
```

...or something along those lines. It has to be in the document for Firefox to process it. Other browsers seem happy even if it isn't in the document.

Comment: request is not for a URL in another origin, "SomeURL" is just "jQuery(location).attr('href')".Problem might be caused by header.Could you suggest any workaround to download file without opening new tab?

Comment: @Wardruna: That's a very convoluted way to access `location.href` (I'm a bit surprised it works). :-) I've updated the answer with a couple of options for triggering a file download.